# How do we prove this identity related to expectation and variance?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, covariance-matrix

Prove that if $\textbf{a}$ is a vector of constants with the same dimension as the random vector $\textbf{X}$, then
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}[(\textbf{X} - \textbf{a})(\textbf{X} - \textbf{a})^{\prime}] = \textbf{Var}[\textbf{X}] + (\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}] - \textbf{a})(\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}] - \textbf{a})^{\prime}
\end{align*}

**MY ATTEMPT**

The first idea which came into my mind was to expand both sides. On one hand, we have
\begin{align}
&\textbf{E}[(\textbf{X} - \textbf{a})(\textbf{X}^{\prime} - \textbf{a}^{\prime})] = \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}\textbf{X}^{\prime} - \textbf{X}\textbf{a}^{\prime} - \textbf{a}\textbf{X}^{\prime} + \textbf{a}\textbf{a}^{\prime}] = \\\\
& \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}\textbf{X}^{\prime}] - \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{a}^{\prime} - \textbf{a}\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}^{\prime}] + \textbf{a}\textbf{a}^{\prime}  
\end{align}

On the other hand, we have
\begin{equation}
(\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}] - \textbf{a})(\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}] - \textbf{a})^{\prime} = \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]^{\prime} - \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{a}^{\prime} - \textbf{a}\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]^{\prime} + \textbf{a}\textbf{a}^{\prime}
\end{equation}

And, finally, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{Var}[\textbf{X}] & = \textbf{E}[(\textbf{X} - \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}])(\textbf{X}-\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}])^{\prime}]\\\\ 
& = \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}\textbf{X}^{\prime} - \textbf{X}\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]^{\prime} - \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{X}^{\prime} + \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{E}\textbf[\textbf{X}]^{\prime}\\\\
& =  \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}\textbf{X}^{\prime}] - 2\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]^{\prime} + \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]^{\prime}\\\\
& = \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}\textbf{X}^{\prime}] - \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]^{\prime}
\end{align*}

Thus, if we add the last two expressions, the desired result is obtained: $\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}]^{\prime} = \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}^{\prime}]$ is always true.

My question is: is there any less tedious way to prove such identity?

Additionally, if $\textbf{Var}[\textbf{X}] = \Sigma = (\sigma_{ij})$, the same exercise asks to prove that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}[\lVert\textbf{X}-\textbf{a}\rVert^{2}] = \sum_{i}\sigma_{ii} + \lVert\textbf{E}[\textbf{X}] - \textbf{a}\rVert^{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Use this one simple trick:  $\textbf{X} - \textbf{a} = \textbf{X} - \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}] + \textbf{E}[\textbf{X}] - \textbf{a}$, and substitute the right hand side into your left hand side formula before expanding.

Comment: You may, without any loss of generality, assume $E[X]=0:$ that helps a bit because it reduces the calculation to one line.  For the additional part, take the trace of the first result.

Comment: Here's another approach, one that requires essentially no computation: look at both expressions as functions of $a.$  Clearly they are quadratic functions. It is immediate that both quadratic terms equal $aa^\prime.$ Linearity of expectation almost as quickly shows the linear coefficients of $a$ are $-2E[X].$  To find the constant term, set $a=0:$ the result is the definition of the variance, *QED.*